# bcrypt encryption with datamapper for codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, datamapper, bcrypt

I'm using codeigniter 2.1.4 with datamapper 1.8.2, have loaded bcrypt however, cannot access it during validation, what could i be missing out? code snippet below.

```
$validation = array(
 'password' => array(
      'label' => 'Password',
      'rules' => array('required', 'min_length' => 6, 'encrypt')
  )
);

function _encrypt($field)
{
   if (!empty($this->{$field}))
   {
      $this->{$field} = $this->bcrypt->hash($this->{$field});
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you've loaded bcrypt as a Codeigniter's library and you can access it in the controller (by $this->bcrypt), but can't access it in your model, right?

If so, in your model call the get_instance() function and change $this to $CI:

$CI =& get_instance();
$this->{$field} = $CI->bcrypt->hash($this->{$field});